# How to handle those properties that don't exist

Tags: javascript

when vm8 occur a property that doesn't exist it shows an error that contain this message:

cannot read property 'value' of null
for example pass id doesn't exist:

```
var pass = document.getElementById('pass');
if (pass.value == '') //here is error that complain about null property
```

my question is how we can prevent compiler to meet this line of code with a proper condition?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Get the element.
// If the element doesn't exist, then it will be `null`
var pass = document.getElementById('pass');
if (pass) {
  alert(pass.value);
} else {
  alert("Element was not found. There is a problem.');
}
```

The line: `if (pass)` could also be written as `if (pass !== null)` but there is no reason to.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if (pass.value == '')`, try

```
if (typeof(pass.value) == 'undefined')
```

Comment: I know what you mean but when compiler faces with this line all script will broken down

Answer (score -1):

You can by various ways:

```
if(typeof(pass.value) === 'undefined')


if(typeof(pass)==="undefined")


if('value' in pass)
```